# Will an optimiser deduce mathematical expressions based on compile-time constants?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

If I have some mathematical equations which rely on inputs which can be zero or non-zero  (template argument, known at compile time), will the optimiser evaluate the equations and optimise out expressions it knows will evaluate to 0 or 1.

For example:

```
double x = y * Eval<type>::value;
```

if `Eval<type>::value` is `0`, `x` will always be `0`.

```
double x = exp(y * Eval<type>::value);
```

if `Eval<type>::value` is `0`, `x` will always be `1`.

Can the optimiser figure this out and replace `x` with `0` or `1` elsewhere in the code, or will these calculations be carried out at runtime?

I am using gcc 4.7 with `-O3`

Comment: If you're familiar with assembly, you can just look at the assembly output of that.

Comment: I bet you could even force it do this at compile time with enough trickery(SFINAE and whatnot).

Comment: The only truly correct answer that can be given to questions of this form is "it is allowed to, but it is not required to."  In this case, add a soupçon of "the compiler usually can't do much algebraic optimization on floating point calculations unless you use the 'go ahead and optimize for speed at the expense of *correctness*' switch."

Comment: Are you sure your assumptions are correct? `y * 0` isn't always zero if `y` is of type `double`.

Comment: SFINAE works perfectly and was what I was writing about, but then I got tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: I was wrong, the compiler works as expected when using a floating point number.**

Well gcc 4.6.3 in `-O3` certainly does seem to do this, as long as the expression is integer related.

Example code:

```
#include <cstdio>
inline int x(double y)
{
   if (y == 0)
      printf("Hello bob3\n");
   else
      printf("Why do I bother\n");

};

const int c = 0;

int main()
{
   int f;
   scanf("%d",&f);

   x(f * c);
}
```

Resulting assembly

```
    .file   "foo.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "%d"
.LC1:
    .string "Hello bob3"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB13:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rsi
    call    scanf
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    call    puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE13:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.6.3-1) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: This only works for the first expression, the second expression is more complex and requires templating stuff